# Minimal Basis of Functional Dependency

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

Please someone help me to get the minimal basis for below FD.

**S = {A->BD, AB->C, C->D BC->D}**

Comment: Is that correct ? A->B, A->C, C->D

Comment: OR A->B, A->C, C->D, BC->D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is your first guess:

```
{ A → B
  A → C
  C → D }
```

In the second one note that there is already C → D, so B C → D is redundant.

Comment: How can you tell, based on the OP, that A -> C?

Comment: @Callum, from A -> BD you can derive A -> B (Decomposition Rule). From this we can add A to both sides (Union Rule), so to derive A -> AB. From A -> AB and AB -> C by transitivity we can derive A -> C. Actually I applied  the algorithm for minimal cover, which is way more simple than using the Armstrong’s rules.